# Validation - 1 Field not greater than another

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, datepicker

I am using 2 jquery datepickers. When the values of the datepickers are equal - I want to prevent Time 2 from being larger than Time 1. The times are 24hr HHMM ( 4 character ) textboxes.

When the datepickers are not equal, anything goes for the Times....

I have it kind of working, but its not exact... I can change the fields and get around the validation which I dont want....

Also dont know if "focusout" is the way to go...

http://jsfiddle.net/rbla/90ps4h9n/5/

html...

```
  Start Date: <input type="text" id="StartDate" name="datepicker1" value="" />
  End Date: <input type="text" id="EndDate" name="datepicker2" value="" />

  <br/><br/>

  Time 1: <input type="text" id="StartTime" maxlength="4">
  Time 2: <input type="text" id="EndTime" maxlength="4">

  <div class="error" style="display:none">Time 1 needs to be less than Time 2<div>
```

javascript...

```
  $(function() {
      $("#StartDate").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
      });
      $("#EndDate").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
     });
  });

  $("#EndDate").change(function () {
      var sDate = document.getElementById("StartDate").value;
      var eDate = document.getElementById("EndDate").value;

      if ((Date.parse(eDate) === Date.parse(sDate))) {

          $("#EndTime").focusout(function(){

          if(parseFloat($("#StartTime").val()) > parseFloat($("#EndTime").val()))
              {
              $(".error").css("display","block").css("color","red");
              $("#submit").prop('disabled',true);
              document.getElementById("EndTime").value = "";
              }
              else 
              {
              $(".error").css("display","none");
              $("#submit").prop('disabled',false);        
              }
         });
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can compare two objects of date Date('date') by comparison operator

```
if(parseFloat($("#StartTime").val()) > parseFloat($("#EndTime").val()))
```

replace

```
if(new Date($("#StartTime").val()) > new Date($("#EndTime").val()))
```

I am not sure I have made exact change as you need. but I have give you idea about date object comparision.